# Can't add constraint on MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I want to add a constraint in a MySQL database with the following code:

```
ALTER TABLE `artikelen` 
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_art_grp` FOREIGN KEY (`groepsid`) REFERENCES `groepen`( 
  `groepsid`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

The properties of both columns are the same.
Type: int(10)
Collation: empty
Attributes: unsigned
Null: No
Default: None

But I'm getting the following error:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bjornm_Keuringsmiddelen`.`#sql-14c6_138c51`, CONSTRAINT `fk_art_grp` FOREIGN KEY (`groepsId`) REFERENCES `groepen` (`GroepsId`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show us the `create table` statement for table `groepen`.

Comment: Here is the code that I used to create the table groepen.
`CREATE TABLE `groepen` (
  `GroepsId` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

  `Groepsnaam` varchar(255) NOT NULL
)
 ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`

Comment: Is it possible that your table `artikelen` is not empty and has a value for `groepsId` that is not in the `groepen` table? Before adding any constraint you must asure that all the rows  comply with that constraint.

Comment: Hi @JaviFernández, Thank you very much! In the records of column `groepsId` from table  `artikelen` there where two values that where not in the column `groepsId` of the table `groepen`. Thanks for the learing lesson of today!

Comment: You're welcome! I added the answer for future visits to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a value for `groepsId` in table `artikelen` that is not in the column `groepen`.

Before adding any constraint you must make sure that **all the rows comply** with that constraint.